# How do you serve a directory listing from restify?

Tags: node.js, express, restify

How do you get Restify to serve directory listings? It seems to be possible to *serve* the contents of a directory, but not actually *list* them.

Comment: Did you try renaming your existing `index.html` to something (maybe `index1.html`) and see if it does the listing or not? (P.S I haven't tried that though)

Answer (score 0):

Use Nodes `fs` library, namely [fs.readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback)

`fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
  console. log(items);
}`

Use that inside a resource endpoint to return the listing.